# Return URI to other class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I want this class, which chooses images out of the gallery and saves the data in the URI to pass this to my imageadapter.class and then display it on the Gridview. How can I do this ?

Thanks,
Code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.addimage:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            openGallery();
            break;
        case R.id.loggout:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "logged out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(nav.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private void openGallery(){
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, IMAGE_PICK);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK){
            imageuri = data.getData();
            System.out.println("success");
        }
}
```

and the adapter's array of images:

```
public static Integer[] images ={
            R.drawable.test, R.drawable.test2, R.drawable.test3, R.drawable.test4, R.drawable.test5, R.drawable.test6, R.drawable.test7, R.drawable.test8
    };
```

Comment: What's the question then?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about sending the result you can do something like so upon successful retrieval of the data,

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK){
            Uri imageuri = data.getData();
            processImageData(imageuri);

            System.out.println("success");
  }
```

Comment: no I am looking for a way to put them into my imageadapter ;)

Comment: Can you share your adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Create a setter method at your adapter like

```
public void setImages(Integer[] images){
 this.images = images;
 notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and in `onActivityResult()` method however method you handle uri with create an array of images and call your adapter variable + setter

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK){
  //handling and create array list of uri
 Integer[] imagesArrayResult = {//......//}
  imageadapter.setImages(imagesArrayResult);
}
```